# Updating Woocommerce Coupon descriptions mysql

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, coupon

in my database this gives me the correct coupon results im looking for

```
SELECT p.`ID`, p.`post_title`, p.`post_excerpt`
FROM   `wp_posts` AS p
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'shop_coupon'
AND pm.`meta_key` = 'product_ids'
AND pm.`meta_value` = '131239'
```

but i need to update all these coupons its over 5k in coupons and the standard import/merge is not updating the coupon description, its essential that our coupons have the correct description due to our accounting system so i need to update them by sql

```
UPDATE p SET p.post_excerpt = 'emesa'
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
AND pm.meta_key = 'product_ids'
AND pm.meta_value = '131239'
```

using update set does not work.

Comment: What details do you need to update ? What is the logic behind it ?

Comment: i need to update the product description which is in the table under post_excerpt

Comment: What is the update condition ? What is the update value ? Under which conditions update can happen ?

Comment: try this -  `UPDATE p SET p.post_excerpt = 'emesa'
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'` ??

Comment: i need to set all coupons descriptions from the coupons with the product_ids of 131239 to emesa

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts AS p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE p.pos' at line 1

Comment: check the answer - there was a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query syntax is different from the Select query. In Update query, you first specify all the tables (including joins) and then use `Set` clause. There is no usage of `From` in the Update query.

From the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>       SET assignment_list
>       [WHERE where_condition]
>       [ORDER BY ...]
>       [LIMIT row_count]
>
> value:
>       {expr | DEFAULT}
>
> assignment:
>       col_name = value
>
> assignment_list:
>       assignment [, assignment] ...

Following will be the correct query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
SET p.post_excerpt = 'emesa'
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
AND pm.meta_key = 'product_ids'
AND pm.meta_value = '131239'
```